# Use .htaccess to block PhantomJS bot

Tags: .htaccess, phantomjs

I want to block traffic from something that appears to be a bot or some other malicious traffic (haven't quite figured out what it is, but I suppose I don't want it). So far I have been blocking it by IP, however the traffic keeps coming from different locations.

Common for this traffic is that the user agent is PhantomJS, and they all show the following local address (perhaps with some variations):

file:///home/poo_master/price_parse/resource_cache/140578757867264tmp2.html

Is it possible to use .htaccess to block either PhantomJS or anything containing "poo_master/price_parse/resource_cache/"

Comment: did you ever figure out what caused this? I have the same.

Comment: No.. I guess it is some kind of price parsing from someone like TradeDoubler/Kelkoo etc.. I know they do some checking, but when I asked their customer service they told me that they did not cause this traffic. But who knows what the guys on customer support knows..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To block bots/scrapers by useragent OR by requested URL add these rewrite rules to .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(PhantomJS|wget|HTTrack|python).*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*poo_master/price_parse.*$ 
RewriteRule . - [F,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your .htaccess file with below code. Hope it will work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(PhantomJS|wget|HTTrack|python).*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*poo_master/price_parse.*$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```